# Rewrite Rule - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here are my current URL:

```
?p=new-homes-by-east-homes&id=416&name=east-homes
```

Here is how I want to have:

```
?p=new-homes-by-east-homes&id=416
```

So far, I have generated this way using .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^p=new-homes-by-([^/]+)&id=([0-9]+)?$  ?p=new-homes-by-place&id=$2&name=$1  [L]
```

This actually works somehow, however, I miss the question mark on front of the new URL `?p=new...`.

When I put the question mark, it jump me to the homepage.

Comment: So where is that URL at ? `yourdomain.com/?p=new...` can detail a bit more on that.

Comment: For pretty URLs, you typically leave out the key=value notation and query string `?` marker. But why do you want to rewrite it at all. If all you need is to drop the `&name=` then just adapt your output code to not include it in links. And you can extract the `east-homes` bit in PHP still.

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string in the pattern of a `RewriteRule`. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var in a `RewriteCond` then use the **%** backreferences:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=new-homes-by-([^/]+)&id=([0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?p=new-homes-by-%1&id=%2&name=%1  [L]
```